# LocationManager in onReceive() won't locate unless I call listener twice, but first call locates, and second call doesn't use new location

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I admit I am relatively new to android, I come from python and C++.  Help would be appreciated.
I am simply calling a location update from Broadcast Receiver onReceive, so that I can text my device and receive it's location, updated at that moment.

I am finding that I can call location be sending text, but it doesn't update the location, it just gives last known.  If I call requestLocationUpdates TWICE, it appears to locate with the GPS icon on the device, but then the second call to requestLocationUpdates doesn't use the updated location, it uses the OLD location.  If I DON'T call requestLocationUpdates TWICE, it doesn't even update (and no GPS icon blinking confirms this.)
Here is my code, with the FIRST redundant call to requestLocationUpdates commented out.
I understand that the code isn't pretty (like the Thread.sleep's, which I intend to remove once the updates are working.. please forgive those temporary bits.
Can somebody PLEASE help me, the code should logically be doing what I want, but logic doesn't seen to work with this one.. :

```
package com.JT.appNew01;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class SmsReceiverXxx extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public static final String COMMAND = "SENDER";
    public static final int SENDER_ACT_DOCUMENT = 0;
    public static final int SENDER_SRV_POSITIONING = 1;
    public static final int MIN_TIME_REQUEST = 5 * 1000;
    public static final String ACTION_REFRESH_SCHEDULE_ALARM =
            "com.JT.appNew01.ACTION_REFRESH_SCHEDULE_ALARM";
    private static Location currentLocation;//was private static
    private static Location prevLocation;//was private static
    private static Context _context;
    private String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    private static Intent _intent;
    private static LocationManager locationManager;//was private static
    //I ADDED FOR FIRST PASS THE FOLLOWING:
    private LocationListener locList=new LocationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                gotLocation(location);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String strStatus = "";
                switch (status) {
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX";
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS";
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_STARTED";
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED";
                    break;
                default:
                    strStatus = String.valueOf(status);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        };// I ADDED THIS TO GO WITH FIRST PASS!!!!!
    private static LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){//was private static
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            try {
                String strStatus = "";
                switch (status) {
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX";
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS";
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_STARTED";
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                    strStatus = "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED";
                    break;
                default:
                    strStatus = String.valueOf(status);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            try {
                gotLocation(location);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            String valuephn=sharedPrefs.getString("welcome_message", "NULL");
            int zz = 0;
            int MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 160; 
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";    
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            if (bundle != null)
            {
              try {
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                    str += "Map Trax - Location: " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";   
                    zz=i;
                }
                   } catch (Exception e){
                         e=e;
                     }
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
                //String xyzx = msgs[zz].getOriginatingAddress();
                String xyzx="a";             // TEMPORARY FOR SKYPE!!! USE LINE ABOVE!!!
                // FIRST PASS TRY TO GET COORDS:
                //try{
                //  //if ( xyzx.contains(valuephn) ) {
                //  if ( xyzx.contains("a") ) {                // TEMPORARY FOR SKYPE!!! USE LINE ABOVE!!!
                //      _context = context;
                //      _intent = intent;
                //      locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                //              .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                //      if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
                //          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_TIME_REQUEST,
                //                  5, locList);            
                //         
                //          Location gotLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                //          gotLocation(gotLoc);
                //          pauseOne();
                //          pauseTwo();
                //          pauseThree();
                //          pauseFour();
                //          pauseFive();
                //          pauseOne();
                //          pauseTwo();
                //          pauseThree();
                //          pauseFour();
                //          pauseFive();
                //          pauseOne();
                //          pauseTwo();
                //          pauseThree();
                //          pauseFour();
                //          pauseFive();
                //          OnNewLocationReceived(gotLoc);//JUST ADDED!!!
                //          stopLocationListener();//JUST ADDED!!!
                //         
                //
                //      } else {
                //          Location gotLoc2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                //          pauseOne();
                //          pauseTwo();
                //          pauseThree();
                //          pauseFour();
                //          pauseFive();
                //          pauseOne();
                //          pauseTwo();
                //          pauseThree();
                //          pauseFour();
                //          pauseFive();
                //          pauseOne();
                //          pauseTwo();
                //          pauseThree();
                //          pauseFour();
                //          pauseFive();
                //          OnNewLocationReceived(gotLoc2);//JUST ADDED!!!
                //          stopLocationListener();//JUST ADDED!!!
                //      }
                //  }}catch(Exception zzz){}
                // END FIRST PASS.
                try{
                //if ( xyzx.contains(valuephn) ) {
                if ( xyzx.contains("a") ) {                // TEMPORARY FOR SKYPE!!! USE LINE ABOVE!!!
                    _context = context;
                    _intent = intent;
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_TIME_REQUEST,
                                5, locationListener);           

                        Location gotLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                        gotLocation(gotLoc);
                        pauseOne();
                        pauseTwo();
                        pauseThree();
                        pauseFour();
                        pauseFive();
                        pauseOne();
                        pauseTwo();
                        pauseThree();
                        pauseFour();
                        pauseFive();
                        pauseOne();
                        pauseTwo();
                        pauseThree();
                        pauseFour();
                        pauseFive();
                        OnNewLocationReceived(gotLoc);//JUST ADDED!!!
                        stopLocationListener();//JUST ADDED!!!
                    } else {
                        Location gotLoc2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                        pauseOne();
                        pauseTwo();
                        pauseThree();
                        pauseFour();
                        pauseFive();
                        pauseOne();
                        pauseTwo();
                        pauseThree();
                        pauseFour();
                        pauseFive();
                        pauseOne();
                        pauseTwo();
                        pauseThree();
                        pauseFour();
                        pauseFive();
                        OnNewLocationReceived(gotLoc2);//JUST ADDED!!!
                        stopLocationListener();//JUST ADDED!!!
                    }
                //sms.sendTextMessage(valuephn,"", "Map Trax - GPS Co-ordinates:"+locationStringFromLocation(null).toString()+" - Map: http://maps.google.com/?q="+locationStringFromLocation(null).toString(),pendingIntent,pendingIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "1: "+locationStringFromLocation(null).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                }
                }catch(Exception zzz){
                    try{
                        if ( xyzx.contains("a") ) {
                            //sms.sendTextMessage(valuephn,"", "Map Trax - GPS Co-ordinates:"+locationStringFromLocation2(null).toString()+" - Map: http://maps.google.com/?q="+locationStringFromLocation2(null).toString(),pendingIntent,pendingIntent);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "2: "+locationStringFromLocation2(null).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                           }
                    }catch(Exception zzzz){
                        //sms.sendTextMessage(valuephn,"","Location currently unavailable",pendingIntent,pendingIntent);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Location currently unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    }
                }
                };
        }
        private void pauseFive() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private void pauseFour() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private void pauseThree() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private void pauseTwo() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private void pauseOne() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public static String locationStringFromLocation(final Location location) {//was public static
            return String.format("%.3f,%.3f", currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        public static String locationStringFromLocation2(final Location location) {//was public static
            return String.format("%.3f,%.3f", prevLocation.getLatitude(), prevLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        private static void gotLocation(Location location) {//was public static
            prevLocation = currentLocation == null ?
                    null : new Location(currentLocation);
            currentLocation = location;
            if (isLocationNew()) {
                OnNewLocationReceived(location);
                //Toast.makeText(_context, "new location saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                //        .show();
                stopLocationListener();
            }
        }
        private static boolean isLocationNew() {//was public static
            if (currentLocation == null) {
                return false;
            } else if (prevLocation == null) {
                return true;
            } else if (currentLocation.getTime() == prevLocation.getTime()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        public static void stopLocationListener() {//was public static
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }
        static ArrayList<OnNewLocationListener> arrOnNewLocationListener =
                new ArrayList<OnNewLocationListener>();
        public static void setOnNewLocationListener(
                OnNewLocationListener listener) {
            arrOnNewLocationListener.add(listener);
        }
        public static void clearOnNewLocationListener(
                OnNewLocationListener listener) {
            arrOnNewLocationListener.remove(listener);
        }
        // This function is called after the new point received
        private static void OnNewLocationReceived(Location location) {
            // Check if the Listener was set, otherwise we'll get an Exception when
            // we try to call it
            if (arrOnNewLocationListener != null) {
                // Only trigger the event, when we have any listener
                for (int i = arrOnNewLocationListener.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    arrOnNewLocationListener.get(i).onNewLocationReceived(
                            location);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: C++ and python ? PauseMinusOne - edit this mess you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a service to update location and start that service when your broadcast receiver received the Sms.

BroadcastReceiver document

**Receiver Lifecycle**

A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.

This has important repercussions to what you can do in an onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation completes.

In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the NotificationManager API. For the latter, you can use Context.startService() to send a command to the service.

Comment: Thank you.  Would the service be a new class or a method within the same class?  What would the code look like?  Could you help me to write this service?

Comment: Move all your codes to a service and in onReceive you just call startService(context, new Intent(context, YourServiceName.class)); You can get some sample of how to write a service at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Hi, i tried it, put the code into a service.  but now, when i run the app, it Toasts the location on startup, but NOT when a text is received.  how do i call the service from broadcastreceiver?  startService(context,new Intent(context,SrvPositioning.class)); doesn't work..

Comment: Post your new code again. Do you declare your service in the manifest?

Comment: Here's the code <code>
public class SmsReceiverXxx extends BroadcastReceiver{

 
  @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) 
     {
...

          startService(context, new Intent(context, SrvPositioning.class));

          context.startService(new Intent(context, SrvPositioning.class));
           
     }
     }
  private void startService(Context context, Intent intent) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub }
</code>

Comment: It is too hard to read in the comment, edit your question to include the new broadcast receiver and some relevant service codes.